# Is there a reason I should reconcile edges?

Tags: simcity-4

Whenever I build something (like roads) right near the edges of the map, the landscape is modified to a configuration that doesn't match the neighboring side. SimCity asks to reconcile edges, but the operation is extremely destructive, blowing up many things that have been built near the edges and even highway cloverleaf interchanges elsewhere on the map.

I can't see any problems if I just refuse to reconcile the edges. Are there any benefits to letting it do so?

Comment: Personally, I thought the inter-region migration/economy wouldn't work if the edges weren't reconciled, so I would always reconcile.

Answer (score 5):

The only effect is visual/aesthetic. Neighbor connections will function fine regardless of any difference in elevation or terrain between two maps.

Answer (score 1):

I only reconcile the edges when I have done significant land re-modelling. Purely for aesthetics, though. So it matches up when looking at the maps in the region view.

Just for roads and minor changes of edges due to buildings I would skip it.

I have turned of the auto-message, because I have accidentally clicked yes before ;-)